# Strange behavior of Java String

Tags: java, string

I came across this program and its not behaving in expected way.

```
public class StringTest
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           String s = "Hello world";
           for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++)
           {
                System.out.write(s.charAt(i));
           }
      }
}
```

If we think it should print Hello world but it prints nothing. What is going on? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to `flush()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want: `System.out.print(s.charAt(i));`

As per the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write(int)) of `write`:

> Note that the byte is written as given; to write a character that will be translated according to the platform's default character encoding, use the print(char) or println(char) methods.

As noted in a comment to your question, if you really wish to use `write()` you need to `flush()`.

---

The reason why `write(int)` doesn't print anything is because it only flushes the stream on `\n` and when `autoFlush` is true.

```
public void write(int b) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
        ensureOpen();
        out.write(b);
        if ((b == '\n') && autoFlush)
            out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but you do not address the main question here: why do characters printed with print() get flushed eventually, whereas characters printed with write() don't?

Comment: @Jeremy: what you have added is correct, but if you look at the code, print(char) just calls write(String) which has the same behavior as write(int). So I still don't get it...

And then Jonathon answered:
@ChrisJ this should be a comment, but to answer the "why": the System class initializes out like this: new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true). It sets the autoFlush to true.

Comment: @Jeremy and @Jonathon: I still don't get it, because print() uses write(), and the auto-flush behavior seems to be coded into write()... So why does print() auto-flush, and not write()?

Comment: @ChrisJ You had me digging through code because you're right, it doesn't make sense at first.  I found that all the `print` methods call a particular `write` method that flushes streams.  The other `write` methods (except for the one called by each `print` print) don't flush the streams.  The one the asker used would not auto-flush.

Comment: @Jonation: Thanks for mentioning that. I noticed the subtle different, too, but I was in a hurry and didn't get to edit my answer. @ChrisJ: Your observations are worth commending, and very interesting.